# Clojure: create a list of values extracted from record

Tags: xml, clojure

I have a data structure of type "clojure.data.xml.Element" that looks like this (pretty printed):

```
{:tag :eSearchResult,
 :attrs {},
 :content
 ({:tag :Count, :attrs {}, :content ("16")}
  {:tag :RetMax, :attrs {}, :content ("16")}
  {:tag :RetStart, :attrs {}, :content ("0")}
  {:tag :IdList,
   :attrs {},
   :content
   ({:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("28911150")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("28899394")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("28597238")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("28263281")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("28125459")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("26911135")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("26699345")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("26297102")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("26004019")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("25995331")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("25429093")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("25355095")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("25224593")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("24816246")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("24779721")}
    {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ("24740865")})}
```

How do I extract the Ids from these records? In other words create a function that takes this data structure and returns a list of Id strings ("28911150" "28899394" ...)?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I've never used the `clojure.data.xml` package, but I'd think you could just solve this with a `(map :content data)`, where `data` is the list of elements.

Comment: I tried making it into a string and parsing it, which worked but is ugly and not generalizable. (map :content x) returns (nil nil nil). I understand the basics of how to work with a map of vectors for example, but I honestly don't know where to begin for this nested structure.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the nesting. You'll probably need to use a recursive function. I'll see if I can figure something out on my break. It should still be doable using `map`, but just check if the content is associative (`associative?`). If it is, recurse into it, otherwise, just apply return it. I can see `mapcat` being useful here. If the data isn't already a string, I wouldn't make it one; that'll just complicate things.

Comment: See pretty printed output, which hopefully makes this a lot simpler :) It is associative.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the `content` will be a non-empty list? Will it always be a list? Trying to think of the best way to differentiate a leaf from a branch. Now that I think about it, this is probably exactly the job for `tree-seq`.

Comment: No guarantee it will be empty. I believe the pubmed API will return an error message somewhere in the XML if the query returns 0 results. I'm happy for now to assume there will be at least one value in the IdList. Thanks.

Comment: I tried writing something in the REPL on my phone, but I'm getting parsing errors with the data you provided. I'll need to wait until I get home on my laptop, although someone else may have answered by then. Look into `tree-seq` in the meantime. That'll probably be the easiest way to solve this. It's a great little function once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that using the basic data accessors from Clojure:

```clj
(->> data                            ; the input
     :content                        ; the content list
     (filter #(= :IdList (:tag %)))  ; only the IdLists
     (mapcat :content)               ; their content as one list
     (filter #(= :Id (:tag %)))      ; only the Ids
     (mapcat :content))              ; one long list of the strings therein
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to add an extra library, this is how it could be done with [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter):

```clj
(def data
  {:tag :eSearchResult,
   :attrs {},
   :content
   [{:tag :Count, :attrs {}, :content '("16")}
    {:tag :RetMax, :attrs {}, :content '("16")}
    {:tag :RetStart, :attrs {}, :content '("0")}
    {:tag :IdList,
     :attrs {},
     :content
     [{:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content '("28911150")}
      {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content '("28899394")}
      {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content '("24740865")}]}]})

(defn tag
  "Build a predicate function to check for a certain :tag"
  [tag-value]
  (fn [e] (= tag-value (get e :tag))))

(use 'com.rpl.specter)

; select, ALL etc is from specter; this defines a path down to the data
(select [:content ALL (tag :IdList) :content ALL (tag :Id) :content FIRST] data)
;; => ["28911150" "28899394" "24740865"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `specter`, you could also [use the `tupelo.forest` library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.cljc#L936):

```
(dotest
  (with-forest (new-forest)
    (let [root-hid   (add-tree-enlive
                       {:tag     :eSearchResult,
                        :attrs   {},
                        :content [
                            {:tag :Count, :attrs {}, :content ["16"]}
                            {:tag :RetMax, :attrs {}, :content ["16"]}
                            {:tag :RetStart, :attrs {}, :content ["0"]}
                            {:tag     :IdList,
                             :attrs   {},
                             :content [
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["28911150"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["28899394"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["28597238"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["28263281"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["28125459"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["26911135"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["26699345"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["26297102"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["26004019"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["25995331"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["25429093"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["25355095"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["25224593"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["24816246"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["24779721"]}
                                 {:tag :Id, :attrs {}, :content ["24740865"]} ]}]})
```

We can find the path from root to each `Id` element, and then extrace the ID string with just 2 lines:

```
          id-content-paths (find-paths root-hid [:eSearchResult :IdList :Id])
          id-strings       (forv [path id-content-paths]
                             (grab :value (hid->leaf (last path))))]
```

The `hid->bush` function prints a Hiccup-like representation of the data tree:

```
  (is= (hid->bush root-hid)
        [{:tag :eSearchResult}
         [{:tag :Count, :value "16"}]
         [{:tag :RetMax, :value "16"}]
         [{:tag :RetStart, :value "0"}]
         [{:tag :IdList}
          [{:tag :Id, :value "28911150"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "28899394"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "28597238"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "28263281"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "28125459"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "26911135"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "26699345"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "26297102"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "26004019"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "25995331"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "25429093"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "25355095"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "25224593"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "24816246"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "24779721"}]
          [{:tag :Id, :value "24740865"}]]])
```

This unit test shows the desired results:

```
  (is= id-strings
        ["28911150"
         "28899394"
         "28597238"
         "28263281"
         "28125459"
         "26911135"
         "26699345"
         "26297102"
         "26004019"
         "25995331"
         "25429093"
         "25355095"
         "25224593"
         "24816246"
         "24779721"
         "24740865"])
      )))
```